# Visual Studio 2008 - Minimap

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

I'm not really sure what to call the "minimap" feature of a text editor.

For example, this editor has what I would call a Minimap feature. A skinny map on the left side where you can click to get to different parts of the file.

http://www.sublimetext.com/

Is there a plugin for VS2008 that has this?

Comment: Funny that you search minimap for Notepad++ on superuser.com too ;)

Comment: As a side note, it appears Visual Studio 2010 will have this built-in.  See the datasheet located here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx and do a search for 'document map margin' in the PDF

Comment: @Daok - Yea, I use notepad++ for php/html stuff. VS2008 for everything else :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx).

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) does that as well.

Comment: RockScroll had too many bugs in it for my taste (VS2008 on Win7), but it's a neat tool. I'm going to try VS2010 which supposedly has it built in.

Comment: @hamlin11, good luck with that, it apparently never got out the door :(